# Why do I get a Symfony NativeSessionStorage error after adding a .theme file?

Tags: theming

After creating (e.g empty) .theme file in my template folder, I get the following error message:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/homepages/d825952918/htdocs/themes/universaldenker/universaldenker.theme" at line 1. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 145 of vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php).

If I delete the .theme file, everything works again. I think it has something to do with opcache, because the path "/homepages/d825952918/htdocs/themes/universaldenker/universaldenker.theme" comes from the .opcache folder.

How can I tell Drupal not to use it and clear all the cached files?

Comment: Maybe add a `<?php` tag to the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your .theme file was not actually empty. Please try the experiment again and check the file size. If it is 3, then your file starts with a Unicode byte order mark (BOM).

The BOM is typically invisible in editors, but it gets sent to the browser before Drupal internally calls the `header()` function. This causes the error message you have seen.

From a glance on your paths, I would not conclude that the OPcache plays a role here.